# Delphi : Access table rows or columns, Finding a way to copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi

I have a Database in Oracle and I copied it to SQL Server using an utility, but it failed in some tables with many rows. So, now they told me to use Delphi to copy each one of the tables that failed into SQL server. The table schema is the same in both Oracle and SQL server, the field type is the same, the utility succeeded in that. What approach can I use? Copy each Column data into SQL server table or fetching each row, putting the data into variables and then insert a row in SQL server?
I started with this code

```
i := 0;
SQLDataSet1.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM LTROUSERS WHERE rownum='+i;
SQLDataSet1.Open;
//how can I get whole row here?

while not SQLDataSet.Eof do
begin
  //get next row
  SQLDataSet.Next;
  i:=i+1;
end;

SQLDataSet1.Close;
SQlDataSet2.Close;
```

Comment: How many rows are you hoping to copy from your Oracle tables that have many rows, roughly?

Comment: 5 million approximatelly, I will use a break or something similar to chain the procedure for every 500 rows...

Comment: For that kind of number, the technique I've used in the past is to write one module that exports from the source server to a per-table textfile, and then uses SqlServer's BCP utility to import the text files.  Much faster than anything I know of that uses Delphi dataset-to-dataset copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really talking about 5 million+ rows, I hope you're not expecting to do this on "live" databases, which are in use by others for inserts/updates/deletes.  You're likely cause the source and/or destination to grind to a halt unless you're v. careful not to.

Consider a) taking the source db offline while you export the source tables to textfiles, then b) using SqlServer's BCP utility (under automation control if you like) to import the textfiles.  That way, you should find you can import several k rows per second on the SqlServer, compared with a few dozen doing a row-by-row copy.  (You would have time to learn BCP from scratch and write the code to use it in less time than 5M rows would take in a row-by-row copy.)

Comment: Many, many years ago (late '90s) I wrote a Delphi application that used this approach from Informix to a SQL Server 6.5! database. It worked really well. I also recall there being a third party ActiveX wrapper available for bcp that allowed better error handling than the command prompt.

Comment: weeeird stuff going on at the office...the head of department said to me to find a way to migrate data from a database in Oracle to SQl Server... Another colleague(head of databases department was away) told me to use Delphi code to do it...And the database has over 5 million rows...wtf.. I am a junior programmer(I was using .NET) and he expects me to do it with Delphi lol!! And this is just an exercise...Looks like someone does not want me in this job LOL...I will just use Toad to export txt files and then import the missing tables into SQL Server

Comment: Well, good luck!  Delphi isn't the ideal tool to handle that number of rows on a row-by-row copy basis, but at least it could assist you in automating the task.  But if it's a on-off, probably easier to do drive Toad etc manually.

Comment: Well, @SamM's shown you a row-by-row method that works fine for smaller numbers of rows, so why not +1 that?

Comment: I will try more on that. I used it today but an error occurred...I ll try to fix it tomorrow. In Toad, I try to select all rows and I get a memory error lol, even toad cannot display all the rows, I ll have to fetch every 100k of them and create many txt files which will be merged into one in the end

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database access method you are using but this example here assumes ADO. You can fit it to whatever access method you are using. If you use transactions you'll need to modify things a bit. And don't forget to handle errors with a try/except around the insert so you don't get left with your records in a weird state.

```
procedure CopyTable;
var FieldIndex : Integer;
  SQLDataSet1, OracleDataSet : Tadoquery;
begin
  SQLDataSet1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM LTROUSERS';
  SQLDataSet1.Open;

  {This assumes that the Oracle table name, Oracle column names, and
   Oracle column data types match SQL Server}
  OracleDataSet.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM LTROUSERS';
  OracleDataSet.Open;

  {Consider adding transaction controls and error handling}
  while not OracleDataSet.EOF do
  begin
    SQLDataSet1.Insert;
    for FieldIndex := 0 to SQLDataSet1.Fields.Count-1 do
      SQLDataSet1.FieldByName(SqlDataSet1.Fields[FieldIndex].FieldName).AsVariant := OracleDataSet.Fields[FieldIndex].AsVariant;
    SQLDataSet1.Post;
    OracleDataSet.Next;
  end;
```

end;

Comment: Errm, the Op wants to copy *from* Oracle, not insert into it?

Comment: I need to get data from Oracle table and copy them to SQL server...Big thank you for the solution, I will try it tomorrow and get back

Comment: @MartynA: whoops! Thanks for catching that. Must be a Monday. Code has been edited above.

Comment: @SamM:  Also "SQLDataSet1.Fields.Count" is missing a " - 1".  Plus, won't the source server be holding a lock on the source table until the SqlServer finishes doing its inserts?

Comment: @MartynA: Oracle usually won't hold a lock on a table unless you specifically direct it to or you set up locking by default for `select` statements. As you said in your answer, the OP needs to tread carefully here if doing this against a live database if the source table data could be modified while doing the copy. With 5 million rows, the Delphi approach can eat up a lot of memory on the client machine if there are a lot of fields too. I'd highly recommend he use a tool designed specifically for database migration because there are optimizations those tools can leverage for bulk loads.